# Why do I get this error? - Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'

Tags: ios, delegates

Why do I get this error message with this code? "Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

I have imported the Appdelegate file - It's been there since the beginning since the app sets it there by default.

I am a bit lost and its the only error I got.

Cheers Jeff

Comment: Yes to both of those - Its even a project that I copied of an older version of the app - same name and the older version does not give the error

Comment: I figured it out why I had the issue:-) - The main.m was importing the right file, however the interface had the wrong name, a typo:-) thanks for the advice:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just check the exact Spelling of your AppDelegate file's name, and make sure you're calling with a correct spelling in the main file...

Might be possible that your actual file name is something like : `Appdelegate.h`

And you're calling it as

```
[AppDelegate class]
```

Comment: It's been checked :-) I even copied it from the left side bar (xcode) and pasted if into the file.

Comment: I figured it out why I had the issue:-) - The main.m was importing the right file, however the interface had the wrong name, a typo:-) thanks for the advice:-)

Comment: Might be my answer was kinda right.. You can accept it of you want :-)